# Цикл вывода стетей/новостей - в теле HTML или отдельно?

Tags: php, mysql

Как лучше выводить статьи/новости на сайте - писать запрос к БД и цикл прямо в теле HTML-документа или создавать отдельный PHP-файл, а потом просто подключать его через include/require? Как правильней и почему?

Comment: Читайте про [MVC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller). Это больше, чем вы спрашиваете, но ответ на ваш вопрос там есть.

Comment: xEdelweiss, спасибо конечно, но это пока что сложновато для меня. Я всего лишь начинающий разработчик, пару месяцев знаком с PHP.

Comment: Там уже во второй строчке ответ на ваш вопрос:
>  разделены на три отдельных компонента так, что модификация одного из компонентов оказывает минимальное воздействие на остальные

Comment: > начинающий разработчик

Не болтайте ерундой! Говнокодер как и все в свое время! До разработчика вам еще далековато)

Answer (score 1):

Надо разделять. Так как отображение - это одно, а логика - другое.

Если захотите поменять выборку, то менять HTML вам необязательно захочется. И наоборот, чтобы добавить что-то в разметку, не надо будет искать её в PHP коде.

Для углубления в эту тему посмотрите в сторону [MVC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), потом можно [HMVC](http://habrahabr.ru/post/113117/). Как это реализуется, в начале, можете и не смотреть, но зачем это делается глянуть стоит.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не могли бы Вы порекомендовать вводные ресурсы или литературу по MVC для совсем начинающих?

Comment: Я не уверен, что MVC - это что-то для совсем начинающих :)  
Главное было понять причины. Остальное сможете найти в сети. Но без понимания ООП разобраться будет сложно.